# Search within date range filtering in cloudant lucene search?

Tags: json, lucene, couchdb, cloudant

In json document, We have start date and end date.

For ex : {"start-date" : "2014-12-05","end-date":"2015-03-15"}

I want to retrieve the records exist between the range of start-date and end-date.How can implement above scenerio in cloudant lucene search?

Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick answer that I haven't tested...

If you store the dates as integers:

```
20141205
20150315
```

You should be able to perform range queries on those values. Here is a snippet from the online documentation:

> You can also perform range facet queries on numeric facets using the
>   ranges= parameter. For example;
>
> ```
> ?q=*:*&ranges={"price":{"cheap":"[0 TO 100]","expensive":"{100 TO Infinity}"}}
> ```
>
> Source: https://cloudant.com/for-developers/search/

**UPDATE:**

The range search should still work even if you keep the original date format (yyyy-mm-dd).

Comment: Doesn't this just return the COUNTS of documents within these ranges, not the actual documents: "return counts of results which fit into each specified category": https://docs.cloudant.com/search.html#faceting

Comment: Furthermore: `The range operation works only if the indexed values are numbers`.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't store dates as integers, which should be the ideal scenario, here is how you should do it in cloudant

1) Edit your search index to use KEYWORD analyzer and then you can pass dates also

```
?q=field_name:["2015-08-17" TO "2015-08-18"]
```

Personally I use multiple analyzers, standard for the rest of the fields and keyword for date fields in cloudant

Comment: Thank you! this was very useful